# How to integrate paytrace payment gateway

Tags: iphone

I am doing a project regarding invoice payment in which all the payment should be done through Paytrace payment gateway. Can you please help me how to do functionality for making payment using Paytrace payment gateway.

Answer (score 0):

Start by reading the API docs. [They can be found here.](http://help.paytrace.com/api)

For a high-level overview of how to call it, read the section "Referencing The API". This discusses how to format your `POST` requests, and provides a few examples of calling the API. Since all requests are just sent as name-value pairs, it's one of the lighter-weight services to integrate. There's no complexity as in WSDL/SOAP/ASMX. Unfortunately, this also means that you cannot use proxy-generation utilities to create a wrapper for you. You'll need to construct each request (as shown in the examples). On the positive side, forming requests is not hard, since the data structures are so flat.

The transaction page gives an example of how to run a transaction:

```
UN~demo123|PSWD~demo123|TERMS~Y|METHOD~ProcessTranx|
TRANXTYPE~Sale|CC~4012881888818888|EXPMNTH~12|EXPYR~12|
AMOUNT~1.00|CSC~999|BADDRESS~1234|BZIP~83852|INVOICE~8888|
```

Note that the name/value pairs are delimited by the "|" character, and the name separated from the value by a "~". Build that string out, `POST` it up to the service, and you'll get back a response which you'll parse out.